# Customize windows, then restore first time setup

Tags: windows-7, windows, computer-building, desktop-customization

How would you go about customizing windows 7 (installing drivers etc.) then deleting the user account used to customize it, and finally restoring the first time setup as if the OS were just installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysprep.exe can be used to strip all the user accounts and passwords and to prepare the system for delivery thus, restoring the first time setup screen. The first time setup screen is called OOBE mode (Out Of Box Experience). Sysprep is located at C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe

If you wish to customize windows in any way right after installing without creating a user, enter audit mode by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F3 at the first time setup screen. The computer will reboot and log in as the built in administrator user. Sysprep will open on login allowing you to easily exit audit mode and return to OOBE mode after you finish customizing.

References: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/33496-63-windows-setup-screen

Answer (score 0):

Create a  user profile B while login as profile A.

Delete the profile A under:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

Restart your PC. Login as profile B.